# How two docker containers communicate each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I've two containers and want to communicate with each other. Container 'A' consist discourse.org application with PostgreSQL database on port 5432, container 'B' has ROR application which running on port 1000. I want to make database connection with ROR app to PostgreSQL(which is in another container). How to connect ROR app with PostgreSQL database?

#### RoR Application, docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 9000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ".:/slackcron"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

#### RoR Application, database.yml

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: discourse
  username: muzammil
  password: '123'
  host: 0.0.0.0
  port: 5432
```

#### docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                NAMES
92a9cb961e56        slackcroncom_app      "bundle exec rails..."   47 seconds ago      Up 46 seconds       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                                               slackcroncom_app_1
b727c2d0d5ba        local_discourse/app   "/sbin/boot"             10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   app
```

Comment: Can you execute `netstat -tuplen` in the database container? It will show if it has bonded to that port and it is listening.

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      107        145283      -                

tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      107        145284      -

Comment: Is your postgres container in your docker-compose.yml or do you run it independently? It's not clear in your question

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460016/connect-from-one-docker-container-to-another)? It seems to be very similar to your question.

Comment: @D.Gonçalves database postgreSQL is running into separate container by docker-compose.yml file

Comment: @Navarro I did it and its shows connection refused

Comment: are you able to resolve discourse.org from your app ?

Comment: You don't need two docker-compose.yml files for DB and for the app. The idea of docker-compose to run and manage several containers by one service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can try to set up discourse in multi-container mode: https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker#single-container-vs-multiple-container
After than, you may have single docker-compse.yml file with struct:
app, db (discourse database) and discourse_app.

Secondly, you can try to run PostgreSQL to outside using `EXPOSE` operator.
Add to your app.yml:

```
expose:
 ...
  - "5432:5432" # PostgreSQL ports
```

You must have password for postgres user:
Enter the container:

```
su - postgres
psql -d postgres -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '<new password>';"
```

Also you can try to use Docker Networking, like this:

```
$ docker network ls

NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
7fca4eb8c647        bridge              bridge
9f904ee27bf5        none                null
cf03ee007fb4        <discourse_name>    host
```

You will see network for Discourse container. You can try use it with your application.

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 9000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
       - ".:/slackcron"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: <discourse_name>
```

After than your RoR application will be run in same network.

Answer (score 2):

Put database to `docker-compose.yml` and add link to it in your app

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:9.4.1
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
  app:
    container_name: app
    build: .
    command: rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - hobover_db
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

and in `database.yml` put your container name as host:

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: db
```

Comment: Its making connection within the same container DB. I want to build connection with another container's DB.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) in docker-compose. You will just have to link to two containers, and inside your configuration, you just reference the service name.

"Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified."

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using container 'A' IP into container 'B' database.yml file and its connected with PostgreSQL

---

Comment: Your containers IP can change, you should use the links in docker-compose, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320696/how-two-docker-containers-communicate-each-other/45321819#45321819